# Como prevenir e remediar quando um web server cai?

Tags: servidor

Gostaria da experiência de vocês.

Atualmente utilizo um servidor que é muito instável. Por muitas vezes o FTP dele cai, e essa semana o servidor ficou fora por 2 dias.

O problema é que não sabemos quando um servidor vai cair e o site ficará fora do ar. Por esse motivo gostaria de saber quais medidas devo tomar afim de prevenir esse tipo de acontecimento, e o que devo fazer quando cair.

Claro que em se tratando de falha no host, não tem o que fazer, e aí teria que partir para a remediação, mas penso em utilizar uma ferramenta de monitoramento para medir tráfego e essas coisas, assim posso saber com antecedência os "problemas".

Também acho que a melhor forma de remediar é ter um host em espera, assim se algo acontecer, mudo o apontamento DNS para o novo host e meu site segue no ar.

O que vocês fariam para prevenir e remediar esse tipo de coisa?

Comment: Sinceramente muda pra Amazon, nunca tive problemas com Servidor. Pode custar caro mais vai valer cada centavo investido. Minha opnião.

Comment: @Marconi, estava pensando nisso também mas temos que ter um volume maior de pessoas no site para fazer isso, por enquanto vou ter que ficar nesse host. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: Já cheguei a ver um da oracle, parece ser muito bom também, ele é bem mais em conta do que a Amazon. Qual servidor você usa?

Comment: @Marconi, hoje estou na Hostnet, mas está fora desde quarta feira. Tive que ficar ligando direto desde sábado para eles me retornarem agora de manhã com uma solução, mas ainda estão trabalhando nisso.

Comment: William não acha que já está na hora de mudar? Um servidor que fica fora do ar por 5 dias é muito tempo, e quanto aos seus clientes? Será que eles vam aceitar isso?

Comment: @Marconi, realmente é um absurdo isso, meio que pegou desprevenido... Eu liguei lá na Oracle e eles não fazem host de website, só de DB e RPM. De qualquer jeito iremos procurar uma outra solução de host. Valeu!

Comment: William a Amazon oferece maquinas gratuitas, porém o hardware não é lá essas coisas. Eu mesmo tenho duas contas lá gratuito que me atendem muito bem nos meus web Sites.

Comment: @Marconi, você sabe dizer se é aquela máquina gratuita por 1 ano e depois tem que pagar? Ou é gratuita pra sempre?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41403/discussion-between-marconi-and-william).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudar servidores DNS gera tempo de espera para atualização. Entendo que a solução é ter um servidor mais confiável. Eu investigaria a causa.

Mas para monitorar se um hostname está no ar use um serviço e monitoração online.
Por exemplo, o Uptime Robot: https://uptimerobot.com

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou ainda o http://www.host-tracker.com/

Localize no Google por: *website monitoring* (https://goo.gl/P4wVyd)

Comment: muito obrigado pelas sugestões, vou dar uma olhada neles e volto aqui!

Comment: Muito boa a resposta. Eu uso newrelic.com